# `Correlation[]` returns incorrect result for TransformedDistribution

Tags: distributions, correlation

Here is the code which calculates the Pearson correlation coefficient affect by the `Ramp[]` function, where `c` is the general form contains the original correlation coefficient $\rho$, and `cs` is the specific form which $\rho=1/2$.

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, \[Rho]}, {\[Rho], 1}}];
\[ScriptCapitalD]s = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}];
c = Correlation[TransformedDistribution[{Ramp[x], Ramp[y]}, {x, y} \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]][[2, 1]];
cs = Correlation[TransformedDistribution[{Ramp[x], Ramp[y]}, {x, y} \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]s]][[2, 1]];
{c /. {\[Rho] -> 1/2}, cs} // FullSimplify
```

However, the two results seems different if applying `\[Rho] -> 1/2` to `cs`.

`c/.{\[Rho] -> 1/2}` returns $\frac{-3 \sqrt{3}-2 \pi +7}{6-6 \pi }$, but `cs` returns $\frac{-3 \sqrt{3}-2 \pi +6}{6-6 \pi }$.

By substituting the formula of Pearson correlation coefficient, we can find that the latter one is correct. I don't know if this is a bug of the `Correlation[]` function.

*Note: Calculating the above expression is time-consuming. It took me about 2 minutes to complete all the calculations on my computer.*

Mathematica version: 12.3.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Note that `MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, ρ}, {ρ, 1}}]` can be expressed more simply as `MultinormalDistribution[{{1, ρ}, {ρ, 1}}]` or even more simply as `BinormalDistribution[ρ]`